# How do I run a script for 1st working day of every month in cron?

Tags: bash, unix, cron

I have to set the cronjob for 1st working day of every month which means **the script should run on 1st working day of every month**.

If suppose 1st working is an holiday then the script should run on the 2nd working day.
For eg: Jan 1 2015 is holiday then the script should run on Jan 2 2015.

Comment: Maybe you could use an intelligent job (program) that checks if today is a holiday or not and then make that code run you job if it is not a holiday. Using cron, you can schedule the intelligent job to run every day. Also, this may be of interest: http://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/199211-run-job-cron-specific-day-excluding-holidays.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, run the `date` command:

```
$ date '+%x'
12/29/2014
```

`%x` tells date to display today's date in the format of the current locale.  Using that **exact same format**, put a list of holidays in a file called `holidays`.  For example:

```
$ cat holidays
01/01/2015
07/04/2015
```

Next, create the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
dom=$(date '+%d') # 01-31, day of month
year=$(date '+%Y') # four-digit year
month=$(date '+%m') # two-digit month

nworkdays=0
for d in $(seq 1 $dom)
do
    today=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%x') # locale's date representation (e.g. 12/31/99)
    dow=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%u')   # day of week: 1-7 with 1=Monday, 7=Sunday
    if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]  && grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays
    then
        workday=Yes
        nworkdays=$((nworkdays+1))
    else
        workday=
    fi
done
[ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 1 ] && /path/command
```

where `/path/command` is replaced by whatever command you want to run on the first working day of the month.  Also, replace `/path/holidays` with the correct path to your `holidays` file.

Lastly, tell cron to run the above script every day.  Your `command` will be executed only on the first working day of the month.

#### How it works

Let's look at the core of the script:

- `for d in $(seq 1 $dom); do`

  This starts a loop running the variable `d` from 1 to the current day-of-the-month.
- `today=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%x') # locale's date representation (e.g. 12/31/99)`

  This sets `today` to the datestring for the day `d` of this month and year.
- `dow=$(date -d "$year-$month-$d" '+%u')   # day of week: 1-7 with 1=Monday, 7=Sunday`

  This sets `dow` to the day-of-the-week for day `d` with 1=Monday and 7=Sunday.
- `if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]  && grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays`

  The test `"$dow" -le 5 ]` verifies that day `d` is a weekday (Monday-Friday). The test `grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays` verifies that day `d`'s date does not appear in the `holidays` file.  If both tests are true, then day `d` is a work day and the `then` clause is executed:
- `then workday=Yes; nworkdays=$((nworkdays+1))`

  The `then` clause sets `workday` to `Yes` and also increments the count of workdays so far this month: `nworkdays`
- `else workday=`

  The `else` clause sets `workday` back to the empty string.
- `fi`

  `fi` signals the end of the `if` statement.
- `done`

  `done` signifies the end of the `for` loop.
- `[ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 1 ] && /path/command`

  The last loop in the `for` statement was for today's date.  Thus, if `workday=Yes` after the loop ends, then today is a workday.  Furthermore, if `nworkdays=1`, then today is the *first* workday of the month.  If both conditions are true, then your command `/path/command` is executed.

Comment: I have a query, here ** if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]  && grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays ** where we have to declare the path of the holiday calender right??

Comment: Other than this, i got everything, Thanks @ John1024

Comment: @Shirchabayshan Just replace `/path/` with the correct path.  For example, if the holidays file is `/etc/holidays`, then use: `if [ "$dow" -le 5 ] && grep -vq "$today" /etc/holidays`

Comment: I have a query @John1024

If suppose
dom=31
today=12/31/2014
if [ "$dow" -le 5 ]  && grep -vq "$today" /path/holidays ( this condition will be true since 31st Dec is not an holiday)
It will enter into the loop.
workday=Yes
nworkdays=1

here
[ "$workday" ] && [ "$nworkdays" -eq 1 ] && /path/command (the condition is true)

But my doubt is how come this will its the 1st working day or not?
the condition will be true for all the working days... After the 1st working day the script should not run...

Comment: @Shirchabayshan Every time it enters the loop, `nworkdays` is _incremented by 1_: `nworkdays=$((nworkdays+1))`.  That means that on 01/01/2014, `nworkdays=1`, and on 01/02/2014, `nworkdays=2`, and on 12/31/2014, `nworkdays=22` (assuming that Christmas was marked as a holiday).  With `nworkdays=22`, the condition will be false and `/path/command` will not run.

Comment: Then, if nworkdays is incremented by 1, then how come the it will work for the next month?
so, before nworkday=0; while($month -le 12). since it will work for 12 months

Comment: @Shirchabayshan `nworkdays` is computed for each month separately.  At the beginning of each month, it starts at zero.

Comment: Could you please tell me how it will assigned with zero every month, because at the end of every month the nworkday=24 or 25; after that how it will become zero. I'm confused with this step.

Comment: @Shirchabayshan Before the loop begins is the statement `nworkdays=0`.  The loop is performed _only_ for the current month, Thus, at the beginning of the current month, `nworkdays=0`.

Answer (score 2):

Cron has no concept of a holiday calendar, nor any hooks to add such a concept.  Sad, but true.  You will need to implement your own holiday calendar (or find one, obviously, but not in cron).  And then you can set cron to run your script every weekday, and your script (or a wrapper) will need to check if it is the first business day of the current month (else exit).

Comment: There is no copy-paste example.  First you need to build or buy a holiday calendar for your own chosen definition of holidays.  Then you need to write a script that uses that calendar.